# javascript htcontents does not show in html correctly

Tags: javascript, show-hide, html-content-extraction

i have a HTML form, user should be able to add other text boxes for a given question. but before any text input, there is a selection of dropdown menu, textboxes become visible after each selection(also depends on the selection, visible textbox count change). here is the javascript;

```
    var var1=1;
        function addAffiliation(){
                    var newArea = addNew();
                    var htcontents ="<input placeholder='categories..'  
class='input_box' type='textbox' name='categories[]' 
onchange='display(this, 'field2', 'field3', 'field4');'/>" 
                        + "<br/><br/>"; 
                    document.getElementById(newArea).innerHTML = htcontents;             
                }
        function addNew() {
                    var1=var1+1;       
                    var var2 = document.getElementById('area');
                    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
                    var divIDName = 'Div #'+ var1;
                    newdiv.setAttribute('id',divIDName);
                    ni.appendChild(newdiv);
                    return divIDName;
               }
```

but when extra field is added, instead of;

```
<input placeholder="categories.."
    class="input_box" type="textbox" name="categories[]"
    onchange="display(this, 'field2', 'field3', 'field4');"/>
```

this is created (double quote location is wrong)

```
<input placeholder="categories.."  
        class="input_box' type="textbox" name="categories[]" 
        onchange="display(this, "field2', 'field3', 'field4');'/>
```

and because of that problem, field2-3-4 is not visible..

what to do?

here is the display function

```
function display(obj,id1,id2,id3) {
    txt = obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].value;
    document.getElementById(id1).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(id2).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(id3).style.display = 'none';
    if ( txt.match(id1) ) {
        document.getElementById(id1).style.display = 'block';
    }
    if ( txt.match(id2) ) {
        document.getElementById(id2).style.display = 'block';
    }
    if ( txt.match(id3) ) {
        document.getElementById(id3).style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

@Aram,

I want to have a dropdown menu;

```
<option name="first">selection 1</option>
<option name="second">selection 2</option>
```

if user selects selection 1;

```
field1:< input name="field1".....>
field2:< input name="field2".....>
```

if user selects selection 1;

```
field3:< input name="field3".....>
field4:< input name="field4".....>
field5:< input name="field5".....>
```

when user finishes filling in the boxes, he might want to add more;

```
addReference();
```

then again he sees,

```
<option name="first">selection 1</option>
    <option name="second">selection 2</option>
```

and so on.. is that clear now?

Comment: Where is the `display()` function  ?

Comment: Isn't here it would seem :P It's a very messy way of handling it, which is why attaching a click event handler in jquery and doing everything in the same js file is better than this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution came very close to what ManseUK suggested,

```
var htcontents ="<input placeholder='categories..'  
class='input_box' name='categories[]' 
onchange='display(this, 'field2', 'field3', 'field4');'/>"
```

should be

```
var htcontents ="<input placeholder=\'categories..\'  //notice slashes
class=\'input_box\' name=\'categories[]\' //notice slashes
onchange=\'display(this, \'field2\', \'field3\', \'field4\');\'/>" //notice slashes
```

hope that helps anyone..

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
var htcontents ="<input placeholder='categories..'  
class='input_box' type='textbox' name='categories[]' 
onchange='display(this, 'field2', 'field3', 'field4');'/>"
```

to

```
var htcontents ="<input placeholder=\"categories..\"  
class=\"input_box\" type=\"textbox\" name=\"categories[]\" 
onchange=\"display(this, 'field2', 'field3', 'field4');\"/>"
```

ie escape the double quotes in the string.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't sure what you did there, because there were syntax errors in addAffiliation near the string. You should use single quotes for the entire string, double quotes for the attribute values and use `+` to concatenate js variables where needed. You must escape any quotes that are the same as those the string is defined with a `\`.

Also, I think `ni` should read `var2`. In general, never name a variable as variableX, because it tells us nothing (we know it's a variable!). Also, I would consider using jQuery to simply the interaction with elements.

See http://jsfiddle.net/ntCGc/.

```
var var1=1;
function addAffiliation(){
    var newArea = addNew();
    var htcontents ='<input placeholder="categories.." class="input_box" type="textbox" name="categories" onchange="javascript:display(this, \'field2\', \'field3\', \'field4\');"/><br/><br/>'; 
    document.getElementById(newArea).innerHTML = htcontents;             
}
function addNew() {
    var1=var1+1;       
    var var2 = document.getElementById('area');
    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
    var divIDName = 'Div #'+ var1;
    newdiv.setAttribute('id',divIDName);
    var2.appendChild(newdiv);
    return divIDName;
}

addAffiliation();
​
```

​

Comment: hi Aram, i did try your advice and used double quotes but there seems to be no change. i am not familiar with jQuery and that is why i tried to code something.

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/ntCGc/ and run the script, you will see the text box added in the div and you can copy the code from there. For jQuery, just go through http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials. But jQuery will only help with things like `document.getElementById(newArea).innerHTML = htcontents;` which would be `$('#'+newArea).html(htcontents);` and so on.

Comment: thanks again Aram. In fact i can add textboxes, but when new div is created, user see a dropdown, after that selection related textboxes does not appear.

Comment: oh, so the other issue is with display... hang on

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do, please explain in the question what display actually does.

Comment: hi Aram, i updated the question. any help is much appreciated.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8126/discussion-between-aram-kocharyan-and-teutara)